# how to calculate $H_2(S^{1}\times S^{1}\times S^{1}\backslash S^{1}\times D)$?

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology

$S^{1}\times D$ is solid torus.    $S^{1}\times D$ is submerged in $S^{1}\times S^{1}\times S^{1}$

Generally,

how to calculate $H_{2}(M\backslash S)$ or $b_{2}(M\backslash S)$ ,  where $b_{2}$ is second betti number.

if $M$ is a  3-manifold (compact, conneted), $S$ is a solid surface
 and $S$ is submerged in $M$.

---

Solution

Let $M=S^{1}\times S^{1}\times S^{1}$

with $T_{s}=(S^{1}\times D_{1})\subset M$ and $M_{1}=M\backslash T_{s}$  later  there is $D_ {2}$  $M_{2}=S^{1}\times D_{2})$ such that

$M_{1}$,$M_{2}\subset M$  and  $M=int(M_{1})\cup int(M_{2})$ with

$M_{1}\cap M_{2}=(S^{1}\times S^{1})\times I$

For $M$,

$H_{0}(M)=H_{3}(M)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $H_{1}(M)=H_{2}(M)=\mathbb{Z}^3$

For $M_{2}$,

$H_{0}(M_{2})=\mathbb{Z}$, $H_{1}(M_{2})=H_{2}(M)+genus(M_{2})=3+1=4$, $H_{2}(M_{2})=?$ and $H_{3}(M_{2})=0$

For $M_{1}$,

$H_{0}(M_{1})=\mathbb{Z}$, $H_{1}(M_{1})=1$, $H_{2}(M_{1})=0$ and $H_{3}(M_{1})=0$

For $M_{1}\cap M_{2}$,

$H_{0}(M_{1}\cap M_{2})=\mathbb{Z}$, $H_{1}(M_{1}\cap M_{2})=\mathbb{Z}^2$, $H_{2}(M_{1})=1$ and $H_{3}(M_{1})=0$\

by Mayer Vietoris,

$$ H_{3}(M_{1})\oplus H_{3}(M_{2}) \stackrel{{h^{3}_{\ast}}}{\longrightarrow } H_{3}(M) \stackrel{\Delta_{2}}{\longrightarrow } H_{2}(M_{1}\cap M_{2}) \stackrel{g^{2}_{\ast}}{\longrightarrow } H_{2}(M_{1})\oplus H_{2}(M_{1})\cdots   $$ $$\stackrel{h^{2}_{\ast}}{\longrightarrow }  H_{2}(M) \stackrel{\Delta_{1}}{\longrightarrow }  H_{1}(M_{1}\cap M_{2}) \stackrel{g^{1}_{\ast}}{\longrightarrow } H_{1}(M_{1})\oplus H_{1}(M_{1}) \cdots   $$ $$\stackrel{h^{1}_{\ast}}{\longrightarrow }  H_{1}(M) \stackrel{\Delta_{0}}{\longrightarrow } H_{0}(M_{1}\cap M_{2}) \stackrel{g^{0}_{\ast}}{\longrightarrow } H_{0}(M_{1})\oplus H_{1}(M_{1})  \stackrel{h^{0}_{\ast}}{\longrightarrow }  H_{0}(M) \stackrel{\Delta}{\longrightarrow } 0$$

replacing

$$0\oplus 0 \stackrel{{h^{3}_{\ast}}}{\longrightarrow } \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\Delta_{2}}{\longrightarrow } \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{g^{2}_{\ast}}{\longrightarrow } 0\oplus H_{2}(M_{1})\cdots   $$ $$\stackrel{h^{2}_{\ast}}{\longrightarrow }  \mathbb{Z}^{3} \stackrel{\Delta_{1}}{\longrightarrow }  \mathbb{Z}^2 \stackrel{g^{1}_{\ast}}{\longrightarrow } \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}^{4} \cdots   $$ $$\stackrel{h^{1}_{\ast}}{\longrightarrow }  \mathbb{Z}^{3} \stackrel{\Delta_{0}}{\longrightarrow } \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{g^{0}_{\ast}}{\longrightarrow } \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}  \stackrel{h^{0}_{\ast}}{\longrightarrow }  \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\Delta}{\longrightarrow } 0$$

then $H_{2}(M_{1})=\mathbb{Z}^3$  such that $H_{2}(M_{1})=H_{2}(M\backslash T_{s})=H_{2}( S_{1}\times S^{1}\times S^{1}\backslash S^{1}\times D)=\mathbb{Z}^3$

please review it.
  If you find any mistake me write. ????????????

Comment: The complement of your solid torus is the intersection of the complements of the two halves of the torus. (Each of these two halves is a 3-cell) This suggests that you can probably try to use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

Comment: Mariano Suárez-Alvarez, thanks for the suggestion. Please you can check my solution,
  you find an error?